GSC is not reading all the sitemaps from the sitemap index file
We are running into some strange issues, where in we have a sitemap index file which has about 25 sub-sitemap links (all on the same domain). But GSC for some reason reads only until sitemap-9.xml. sitemap-10.xml, sitemap-11.xml and so on is not successfully read. If I manually try to hit sitemap-11.xml then it says "Couldn't fetch", even though the pages load fine on the normal browser and are not blocked from our backend servers.
Appreciate if anyone can support on this.
